# Magento Import Using Magmi - Admin Images Not Displaying

Tags: magento, csv, import, admin, magmi

Ive successfully imported various products using the Magmi module. The images are showing in the front end but not in the admin of Magento I am using Magento 1.7X and Magmi v0.7.18.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks,

Comment: Is the image URL just giving a 404, or is an error being logged?

Comment: Hi, the image isn't loading in admin but displays in front end, there is no error 404.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in your CSV file, change all your **_media_attribute_id** values to 88. You can double check this number by exporting your products to a CSV file on your new install and check what this value is.